# ant script to ignore certain part of xml

Tags: ant

in the following xml file, while running the ant script, i am getting the error C:\Work\6.70_Extensions\ANTScripts_Check_IN.xml:134: Could not create task or type of type: buildmachine4.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project name="TrueCM_Checks" default="help">
        <taskdef name="CFileEdit" classname="com.ANT_Tasks.CFileEdit"/>


<!-- ========================================================== -->
<!--  init                                                      -->
<!-- ========================================================== -->
    <target name="init">
        <property file="..\Master Build.properties"/>
        <property file="TrueCM.properties"/>
    </target>


<!-- ========================================================== -->
<!--  main                                                      -->
<!-- ========================================================== -->
        <target name="main" depends="init">

            <ant antfile="..\Master Build.xml" target="Print Properties"/>

            <tstamp>
                <format property="BUILD_DATE" pattern="d-MMMM-yyyy hh:mm aa" locale="US"/>
            </tstamp>

            <echo message="BUILD START: ${BUILD_DATE}"/>

            <parallel>
                <antcall target="Check IN Master Build.xml"/>
                <antcall target="Check IN Master Build.properties"/>
                <antcall target="Check IN TrueCM_Check_INOUT.xml"/>
                <antcall target="Check IN TrueCM.properties"/>
                <antcall target="Check IN TrueCM_SnapShots.xml"/>
                <antcall target="Check IN TrueCM_Update.xml"/>
                <antcall target="Check IN ANTScripts_Check_IN.xml"/>
            </parallel>


            <tstamp>
                <format property="BUILD_DATE" pattern="d-MMMM-yyyy hh:mm aa" locale="US"/>
            </tstamp>

            <echo message="BUILD END: ${BUILD_DATE}"/>

        </target>


        <target name="Check IN Master Build.xml">
            <echo>Checking IN Master Build.xml;</echo>
            <exec executable="${TrueCM_App}\${TrueCM_Mode}"   failonerror="true">

                <arg line='-I "C:/Work/${TrueCM_Tip}/release/SASE Lab Tools/ANT Builds/Master Build.xml"'/>
            </exec>

        </target>

...
...



<!-- ========================================================== -->
<!--  Check Out                                                 -->
<!-- ========================================================== -->
    <buildmachine4>
        <checkout1 exe="wco" folder='-f -R "C:/Work/6.70_Extensions/ANT Builds/"'/>
        <checkout2 exe="wco" folder='-f -R "C:/Work/7.00_Extensions/ANT Builds/"'/> 
    </buildmachine4>
    <buildmachine5> 
        <checkout3 exe="wco" folder='-f -R "C:/Work/7.10.00_Tip/ANT Builds/"'/>
    </buildmachine5>    
</project>
```

the error is because of the `<buildmachine4>` and `<buildmachine5>`. how can i ensure that it will ignore `<buildmachine4>` and `<buildmachine5>`? these contains parameter for my user interface.

Answer (score 1):

The buildmachine tags are not defined in your buildfile..

If you want to make buildmachine valid ant tasks you need to define them as a task (http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/taskdef.html) and use them inside a target.

```
  <taskdef name="buildmachine4" classname="com.mydomain.BuildmachineTask"/>
```

Otherwise you may have to uncomment those lines

```
<!--buildmachine4>
        <checkout1 exe="wco" folder='-f -R "C:/Work/6.70_Extensions/ANT Builds/"'/>
        <checkout2 exe="wco" folder='-f -R "C:/Work/7.00_Extensions/ANT Builds/"'/> 
    </buildmachine4>
    <buildmachine5> 
        <checkout3 exe="wco" folder='-f -R "C:/Work/7.10.00_Tip/ANT Builds/"'/>
    </buildmachine5-->
```

That's all I can think of.